# Statement similar to which() for a list of S4 objects

Tags: r, r-s4

I have a list `mem.shapes` of objects of class `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`.  Each list element contains a slot `mem.shapes[[i]]@data`, which is a data frame that includes a column `mem.shapes[[i]]@data$SCINAME`.

I would like to extract the elements of `mem.shapes` that have a particular character string in `mem.shapes[[i]]@data$SCINAME[1]`.  The following code gives what I want:

```
SCINAME <- vector(mode="character", length=length(mem.shapes))
for(i in 1:length(mem.shapes)){
    SCINAME[i] <- as.character(mem.shapes[[i]]@data$SCINAME[1])
}
which(SCINAME=="Dendroica magnolia")
```

But I imagine there is a cleaner way to do this--some kind of `which`-like statement that can "reach inside" the `@data` slot of the list elements to return the indices `i` that have `mem.shapes[[i]]@data$SCINAME[1]=="Dendroica magnolia"`

Apologies if this has been answered before; I was unable to find it despite searching.  I would appreciate help making my question more general and more searchable, since I imagine this must be a reasonably common issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use apply functions to find the matches.

First let's create some S4 data to test this on. For simplicity, I'll use the Matrix package which returns S4 classes.

```
library(Matrix)
set.seed(123)
m <- Matrix(sample(1:6, 100, replace=T) ,ncol = 10,sparse = T)
```

now use sapply to find values of m@x that equal 5

```
unlist(sapply(1:length(m@x), function(i) {if(m@x[i]==5) i}))
# [1]  2 13 22 26 33 34 37 53 58 65 67 68 69 71 73 82 84 97
```

Note that, of course, in this simple example `which(m@x==5)` would have served the purpose.  But this method can be extrapolated to OP's example of drilling down levels in a more complex S4 structure.  E.g. the following should work on OP data (although this is not tested as data were not provided).

```
unlist(sapply(1:length(mem.shapes), function(i) {
  if(as.character(mem.shapes[[i]]@data$SCINAME[1])=="Dendroica magnolia") i}))
```

For convenience, you can wrap this in a function

```
which.i <- function(i, expr) {
  unlist(sapply(i, function(i) {if(eval(parse(text=expr))) i}))
}

which.i(1:length(m@x), "m@x[i]==5")
# [1]  2 13 22 26 33 34 37 53 58 65 67 68 69 71 73 82 84 97
```